# AKS cannot pull docker image from private registry with letsencryptcertificate

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am gettix x509 certificate issue when AKS is trying to pull docker image from my private repository secured with LetsEncrypt certificate. How can I menage certificate store in AKS to add CA of my certificate etc.

Comment: I'd guess you'd need a daemonset on aks nodes to modify certificate store. but I'm not sure why that is needed, LE certificates are trusted. can you share the actual error and whatever you are doing to get it?

Comment: kubelet Failed to pull image "my registry/my-image:lts": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://my registry/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Comment: Please paste exact error and logs from below answer to your post and also provide more details about environment are you working on and yaml files (deployment, service). If you are using specific tutorial please provide link to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Normal   Scheduled  8m8s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/proxy-deployment-568646f8d4-7gnnt to aks-default-26787434-vmss000000
```

Normal   Pulling    6m34s (x4 over 8m7s)  kubelet            Pulling image "my registry/my-image:lts"
Warning  Failed     6m34s (x4 over 8m7s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "my registry/my-image:lts": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://my registry/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Warning  Failed     6m34s (x4 over 8m7s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
Normal   BackOff    6m18s (x6 over 8m7s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "my registry/my-image:lts"
Warning  Failed     3m5s (x19 over 8m7s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff